# Prepare data in controller, not in view (yii)

Tags: yii, controller

I made "gearbox"-dropDownList in my Yii webapp, all works perfect, it stores in DB with next values ( 1=> Manual, 2=> Manual-Automat(tiptronick), 3=> Automat), and now i display it in template (view.php) with such not beautiful if-block:

**Gearbox:**
" 
    if ($model->gearbox == 1) {
        echo 'Manual';
    } elseif($model->gearbox == 2) {
        echo 'Manual-Automat';
    } else {
        echo 'Automat';
    }
"

Tell me please, should I prepare such data in controller? And if it is possible, can you advice me, please, how it doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this simple case there is not much to do, but you could prepare it in your controller like this:

**Controller:**

```
  if ($model->gearbox == 1) { 
     $gearbox = 'Manual'; 
  } elseif($model->gearbox == 2) { 
     $gearbox = 'Manual-Automat'; 
  } else { 
     $gearbox = 'Automat'; 
  } 

$this->render('view',array('gearbox'=>$gearbox))
```

**View:**

```
echo $gearbox;
```

Comment: of course with more complex data it will be more complex. You can also use custom functions in the Controller, or in the model (like in the answer from Michiel) to make code more readable. Please upvote/accept the answer if you are satisfied :)

Answer (score 1):

A other option would be to add this to your model with a [virtual attribute](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/), like this:

```
public function getGearboxName() {
    if ($model->gearbox == 1) {
        return 'Manual';
    } elseif($model->gearbox == 2) {
        return 'Manual-Automat';
    } else {
        return 'Automat';
    }
}
```

This way you can access the value by the `gearboxName` attribute in your model:

```
echo $model->gearboxName;
```

Comment: yeah, i see it's the way to avoid of multi-copy of code in every method.
Take this opportunity i'd like to congratulate you with our professional holiday- "Webmaster's day", which is celebrates on 4 aprils

Comment: of course if you need the code more times, this is the best way. But if you use it only once in the controller, I would not pollute the whole model with it :)

Comment: Even better would be to create a relation so you can access the name by `$model->gearbox->name` :-)

Comment: good, now i'm trying to use it multiple times. So if I display it in my view.php template, it works fine, now I want to display it in _view.php template, so, I think, I must use renderPartial.